# Transactional Security for Data Loader - tracking exported records

Tags: data-loader

I have a Transactional Policy Setup for Data Export via Data Loader whihc is triggering as expected. Is there a way to determine what entity (records) were downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately - no. Your only control along these lines is the number of downloaded records. See the `data` property in [TxnSecurity.Event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_TxnSecurity_Event.htm#apex_class_TxnSecurity_Event) class with `DataExport` as the event, these are your available policy controls.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will check on it and update you.

Comment: They revamped this whole area in Winter '20: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_security_em.htm